# How do I prevent Resharper Javascript Intellisense from replacing 'function' with 'Function'?

Tags: resharper, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I have a problem where 'function' is almost always replaced by 'Function' even after I type the entire word, which is happening all too often and drives me absolutely batty. I have to back up and replace the first letter. Any way to adjust this? I don't even know where I'd use 'Function'.

Comment: what version of resharper are you using?

Comment: The edge version of 8.1 in VS 2012

Comment: Are you in a file that is *.js or something else?  Resharper may not realize you are in the js context

Comment: *.js is correct. I get all the appropriate intellisense...it's just that it's always attempting to perform the replacement as mentioned.

Comment: I am also experiencing a similar issue in 9.1, in which it renames globals, like `console -> Console` and `window -> Window`

Comment: ugh that `Window/Console` replacement drives me mad. @ZacharyKniebel, were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @MaksimVi - I installed an update (not sure if it is still the latest, but it was at the time) about a month ago and the issue stopped occurring. I can also confirm that the issue is not happening in the latest version of ReSharper 8.2.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel, sad it's still there in 9.1

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but I remember that when I did the update, I cleared out all of the ReSharper caches too. I did find an answer to the same `function` -> `Function` issue that says to clear ReSharper's intellisense caches so that could have been part of it too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21312961/1506793

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JetBrains appears to have this issue logged as a bug and supposedly fixed. Problem is that the fix seems to be first applied to 7.0.1 but is now apparent in the latest 8.1 again.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-330134

I have made comments, but if anyone else is also having this problem please continue to add to the thread.