# Why does IntelliSense keep changing function to Function?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, javascript-intellisense, resharper-8.0

I am having a very strange IntelliSense issue, and I'm not sure if it's Visual Studio 2013 or ReSharper 8.1.  When I'm working in views (cshtml) within `script` tags (javascript), something keeps changing "function" to "Function" with a capital "F."

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something = function() .... //on tab or completing the ()'s, it changes to Function
</script>
```

This isn't a huge deal, of course, but it's becoming a pain in my neck as I keep having to go back and lower-case the "F."  Does anyone know why this is happening?

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with ReSharper 8.1 C# edition.

Comment: could it be your Resharper cache needs clearing, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283306/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-entry-from-intellisense-resharper

Comment: @PiersMyers Hmmm, clearing the cache seems to have resolved it.  You should post your comment as an answer so I can upvote and select as answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clearing the caches would probably work - `Resharper`->`Options`->`Environment`->`General` and click the `Clear Caches` button.

Comment: I have the same problem and setup, but clearing the cache doesn't help :(

Answer (score 7):

I'm experiencing the same issue with ReSharper 8.1.23.546, and it hasn't been resolved with a cache clear. It is reported to have been fixed in build 8.1.1000+

The only thing that worked for me was to disable auto-popup for JavaScript, as described here:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-400812

- Go to Resharper > Options > Intellsense > Autopop > JavaScript
- Choose 'Display but do not preselect' for all the drop down items

This is less a fix than a way to make the irksome behavior go away until I can get an upgrade.

I love ReSharper, but this was annoying enough that I was contemplating buying a ticket to the Czech Republic to poke someone in the eye.

Comment: Yes, this is very annoying. I have the same build and the issue is definitely there.

Answer (score 5):

Clearing cache didn't fix my issue.  The best fix for me was to remove the "(" character from being able to auto-complete in my JS since I always just type "function(".

I did this by going to Resharper > Options > Intellisense > Completing Characters, and put a "(" in the Do not complete on box for JavaScript.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was having issues with R# grabbing every function it could find instead of what is in the _refereneces.js file so I changed the intellisense to use visual studio's instead of R#.

[image]